# Using non-English controllers in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to following problem:

If i want to follow the Rails naming convention i have to use the plural version of the model's name as my controller name.

Example:

```
rails g scaffold_controller Content
```

In this case i have a model(Content) and the previous command is going to generate a controller with the name Contents.

So what if I have a German website and I would like to use *site.tld/inhalt/something-something* instead of *site.tld/contents/something-something*.

I was thinking about two solutions:

a, use the German version of the word when I am generating the controller(afaik it is not supported by the scaffold_controller generator

b, generate the whole site(models, controllers) in English and route the specific request to a certain controller with named routes like:

```
match 'logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
```

In this case I can't use RESTful routes like:

```
resources :products
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use routing configuration to change the url that matches this controller:

```
resources :contents, :path_names => { :new => 'neue', :edit => 'bearbeiten' }, :path => 'inhalt'
```

The `contents_path` method in your view will still work, but it'll output `/inhalt` as required and that will match. The `/contents` path won't match though. So if you call `edit_content_path(@content)` you'll get something like `/inhalt/1/bearbeiten`.

See [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more details.